# Aggregation -> Sample -> Documents Pattern in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm not so well-versed on all things MongoDB, but I'm hitting a problem which I'm struggling to find an answer for (the docs aren't always clear).

In essence, I have a large collection of documents with this type of structure:

```
{'addr': 'x@a.com', 'rep': 2, ... } // there are 100s of fields
{'addr': 'x@b.com', 'rep': 2, ... } 
{'addr': 'x@c.com', 'rep': 2, ... } 
{'addr': 'x@a.com', 'rep': 2, ... } 
{'addr': 'x@b.com', 'rep': 2, ... } 
{'addr': 'x@c.com', 'rep': 2, ... }
```

Then, what I want to do is to group by the addr, sample say a max of 1000 of each group, then output all the documents in pymongo.

What I have now is something like

```
aggs = mongo['db'].db.data['collection1'].aggregate([{'$group': {'_id': '$addr'}}, {'$sample': {'size': 10}}])
```

I saw that I can use project to output all fields (I think), but is there a way to access the results of each aggregation so that I can do something like:

```
for agg in aggs:
    for result in agg.results:
        print(result)
```

Comment: So you want to print result from each stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do it like that. Once you `$group` you need to specify how you want to aggregate any fields to be projected, so you lose the resolution you're after. I'd be inclined to keep it simple and do it in two hops. One to get the list of distinct `addr`s and then perform your sample on each group; something like:

```
addrs =  db.collection1.distinct('addr')

for addr in addrs:
    aggs = db.collection1.aggregate([{'$match': {'addr': addr}},
                                     {'$sample': {'size': 10}}])

    for agg in aggs:
        print(f'{addr}, {agg}')
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is how I'm doing it now, but it's super slow :(

Comment: Well you're unlikely going to improve performance by using an aggregate query. The problem is `$sample` is just plain slow. Do you have an index on `addr`?

Comment: :( I added the index to addr and iterate over each of the addresses that have more than X occurrences.

`
    aggs = db.collection1.aggregate(
        [{'$group': {'_id': '$addr', 'num_records': {'$sum': 1}}},
         {'$match': {'num_records': {'$gte': 50}}}])

    for agg in aggs:
        _agg_docs = db.collection1.find({'addr': agg['_id']}).limit(1000)
        docs += [doc for doc in _agg_docs]
`

This is fine :)